# How to test NLP model against many strings

Tags: python, nlp, logistic-regression

I have trained a classifier model using logistic regression on a set of strings that classifies strings into 0 or 1. I currently have it where I can only test one string at a time. How can I have my model run through more than one sentence at a time, maybe from a .csv file so I dont have to input each sentence individually?

def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid,valid_y, is_neural_net=False):
        classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

```
# predict the labels on validation dataset
predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

if is_neural_net:
    predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)

return classifier , metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, valid_y)
```

then

```
model, accuracy = train_model(linear_model.LogisticRegression(), xtrain_count, train_y, xtest_count,test_y)
```

Currently how I test my model

```
sent = ['here I copy a string']
```

converting text to count bag of words vectors

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2))
x_feature_vector =  count_vect.transform(sent)
pred = model.predict(x_feature_vector)
```

and I get the sentence and its prediction

I wanted the model to classify all my new sentences at once and give a classification to each sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[model.predict(X)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) takes a list of samples, the same for [count_vec.transform(X)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.transform) so you can read sentences from file and predict them together like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    samples = f.readlines()
    vecs = count_vec.transform(samples)
    preds = model.predict(vecs)
    for s, p in zip(samples, preds):
        #printing each sentence with the predicted label
        print(s + "     Label: " + p)
```

Comment: Your code wasnt closing after the 'open' portion. I had to put `with open('test1b.txt', 'r',errors='ignore') as f`. Additionally, had to use the zip function `for s, p in zip(samples, preds)`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way to go will be

```
vecs=count_vec.transform(test['column_name_on_which_you_want_to_predict'])
pred=model.predict(vecs)
data=pd.DataFrame({'Text':column_name,'SECTION':pred})
```

you can export it then as you want.